# how can I make Html5/Javascript canvas fill window screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, html5-canvas

I'm beginner in HTML and made a HTML5 game with Tululoo (http://www.tululoo.com/) .. this "example" (http://trailsite555.eu.pn/game/) works fine ,but is there a way to make the canvas fill the browser window? (like Chrome/Firefox) ,and is there a way to fill mobile screen too?

Answer (score 0):

canvas tag is not in percent but in pixels only.

So you have to compute the actual dimension of the viewport and apply it to your canvas.
The you still have to hide the scroll bars in CSS.

Here is the code:

```
//return an obect with the dimension of the viewport of the browser
function getViewportDimension() {
var e = window, a = 'inner';
if (!( 'innerWidth' in window )) {
    a = 'client';
    e = document.documentElement || document.body;
}
return {w:e[a + 'Width'], h:e[a + 'Height']};
}

//apply the dimension to the canvas
var dim = getViewportDimension();
canvas.width = dim.w;
canvas.height = dim.h;
```

The CSS code to hide the scrollbars:

```
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Just remember that resizing the canvas will clear it's content.

Comment: thanks ,but I didn't know where to put it.
anyway these 2 days I'm busy I'll try do it later.

Comment: The quick and dirty way is to put the JS in your html page, just after the creation of the canvas tag. The `canvas` variable is the handler to your canvas tag, catched for example with JQuery. Regarding the CSS, it's just a normal call :)

Answer (score -1):

That line of code

```
<canvas id="[object Object]" width="640" height="360" style="background-color: rgb(46, 90, 65); border: 0px;"></canvas>
```

Why did you make it `width="640"` and `height="360"` ?

change them both to 100%, it should fix it up.

Comment: with tululoo I couldn't do this? ,it's built-in ..
tried to change it and it didn't work , see this file if you can edit something : http://trailsite555.eu.pn/game/game.js
after changed it : http://trailsite555.eu.pn/game/gameAfter.js

Comment: Look, after you finish the project, open the HTML file with any editor, even notepad, and change the values to 100% as I explained before. Unfortunately I'm not home now, but later I'll try to do it myself for you, but I prefer that you'll try it yourself so you can learn better that way. Good luck mate. ;)

Comment: tried ,and didn't work ...
I think tululoo using a complex method can't be edited ..